# Finding ground state energy from hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian

My question is, given a Hamiltonian lets say H = Sz(where Sz is pauli spin matrix). Is it possible to find the ground state energy from the above mentioned Hamiltonian.

As I understand finding the eigenvalues of the Hamiltonian matrix yields two eigenvalues namely (h/2) and (-h/2). Can these be considered as energies and if so what would be the ground state energy??